# Appending 2 data sets whilst keeping the header

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I am trying to extract a few items from an Excel file and subsequently save them into a separate Excel file.

For example, I am trying to:

1. Select only transactions that is 500 and above from Column G
2. Randomly select 3 transactions from the remaining items in the original Excel file
3. Save these transactions into a new Excel file
4. I need the heading (first row) in this new Excel file

```
A  B  C  D  E  F   G
x  x  x  x  x  x  100
x  x  x  x  x  x  10
x  x  x  x  x  x  500
x  x  x  x  x  x  1000
x  x  x  x  x  x  20
x  x  x  x  x  x  10
x  x  x  x  x  x  10
x  x  x  x  x  x  30
x  x  x  x  x  x  50
```

I am thinking if I could use the Append function ? I am not really sure how to work on it.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import openpyxl 
from numpy.random import choice

df = pd.read_excel('filepath', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

df1 = df[df['G'] >= 500]
df2 = df.loc[choice(df.index,3)]

## After appending df1 and df2
.to_excel('filename.xlsx',index=False) # to save to new Excel file
```

I am unsure on how to append `df1` and `df2` whilst keeping the header (first row).
Please advise how can i do it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Didn't try on your data, but you can probably obtain the dataframe you want using **df = df1.append(df2)**

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

```
combined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
combined_df.to_excel('filename.xlsx',index=False)
```